# Google Wallet for Digital Goods API doesn't offer a field to input the tax

Tags: android-pay

I am using the PHP API of Google Wallet for Digital Goods, but I can't find the proper field to insert my tax value.

At the popup window where the user makes the checkout, doesn't matter how I change, the value tax is always 0.00. I have been searching on internet and seems that other developers are facing same problem and can't find any answer so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tax rates can be configured in the Google Wallet Merchant Center (Merchant Settings -> Sales Tax). You can specify a tax rate for each region.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, there isn't one ([specific field for tax](https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/jsreference#jwt))..

You'll likely have to include that in the total `price` if you need to charge sales tax. You can then provide the necessary detail to your customers in some way (e.g. your own "receipt").

The `sellerData` field maybe something that you can use for your purposes as well..perhaps transaction detail could be there so you can present it in some way to your customer upon hitting `successHandler` (?)

Hth...

Comment: Yes, including the tax in the total price is what I'm already doing. What puzzles me is why Google Wallet shows the Tax field on the checkout modal screen if we can't really use it.
Looks like this APIs have been manage by trainees, not by real engineers.

Comment: @thelaughingman Hmm...my _sandbox_ account is hosed and it's been some time. Is there some tax setting there (account level)?